# "Add field" in a simple Javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a calculator on a website that I am looking for some help with. The company sells mulch, and has a mulch calculator that their customers can use to find out how much mulch they approximately need to order.

Currently the form allows you to enter the length, width, and depth of your mulch bed and it outputs how many cubic yards of mulch you will need to order.

I've been asked if I can add a part to the form which allows a used to "add a field" to the form. In other words, just add another length/width/depth section in there, and the final result would add the two together.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
        <form name="mulchForm" class="contact-form clearfix">

            <p>Enter Mulch Bed Length</p>

            <p>
            <input type="text" class="left" name="length" placeholder="Enter length (in feet)" />
            </p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <p>Enter Mulch Bed Width</p>

            <p>
            <input type="text" class="left" name="width" placeholder="Enter width (in feet)" />
            </p> 
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <p>Enter Mulch Bed Depth</p>

            <p>
            <input type="text" class="left" name="depth" placeholder="Enter depth (in inches)" />
            </p> 

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!--Form buttons -->
            <p>
            <input type="button" onClick="calculate();" value="Calculate">

            <input type="button" onClick="mulchForm.reset();" value="Clear Form">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </p> 

            <p>Approximate Number of Cubic Yards of Mulch Needed:</p>
            <p><input type="text" class="left" name="cubicYards" placeholder="Number of cubic yards needed" /></p> 

        </form>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        document.mulchForm.cubicYards.value = (document.mulchForm.length.value/3) *
                                              (document.mulchForm.width.value/3) *
                                              (document.mulchForm.depth.value/36);
    }
</script>
```

Currently, the form just allows for one length/width/depth to be entered, I am trying to find out how to add something that lets me click a +Add Field button which pops up with another set of length/width/depth boxes for them to use. The end result would add all fields together.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it a lot of ways.. you can look at this.. http://jsfiddle.net/BRNZC/
instead on adding more text boxes you and just keep a list and a running total.
with a little formatting you can make it look pretty.. I would put it in a table and make the list appear on the right of the form..

give you a start

```
<div id=list></div>
<div id=total></div>


<input type="button" onClick="add();" value="Add">


   function add() {
       total = (document.mulchForm.length.value / 3) * (document.mulchForm.width.value / 3) * (document.mulchForm.depth.value / 36);
       document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += document.mulchForm.length.value + "x" + document.mulchForm.width.value + "x" + document.mulchForm.depth.value + "=" + total + "<br>"
       runningtotal += total
       document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total = " + runningtotal
       document.mulchForm.length.value = ""
       document.mulchForm.width.value = ""
       document.mulchForm.depth.value = ""
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. This isn't exactly what I had in mind, but it is a good quick fix that I think will work for what they need. One last question, how would I go about rounding the decimal places on the outputs? I think that would look a lot prettier, and I guarantee someone isn't going to need exactly 230.4829399999 cubic yards of mulch :)

Comment: Math.round(runningtotal)